# modprobe -all not working on latest gentoo

Tags: linux, gentoo

Hi I am new to linux OS.
I have downloaded latest install-amd64-minimal-20141204.iso from http://distfiles.gentoo.org/releases/amd64/autobuilds/current-iso/.
  **When I run modprobe -all command I am getting error as modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'**.

The above command was working on older version of gentoo.

Can anyone please help me how to fix this issue or any replacement of this command.

Note: gentoo kernel version is Linux livecd 3.16.5-gentoo.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably run `modprobe` with `-a` or with `--all` option. Notice double dash. Check `man modprobe` for more info.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried  both the options but no luck. I am getting same error.